# Sonar integration tests againts java classpath jars

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I´m having a module C which contains a jar files from modudle A and B
I´m running a java process with CP java -cp A.jar B.jar Main.class and I´m running some integration tests. 
Then a jacoco-it.exec file it´s created in C module, but I´´m afraid that when Sonar Queue scan the module in C tell me

```
10:55:50.562 INFO  - Analysing D:\Users\nb38tv\workspace\WS_F2ECORE_LTD\DG2\core\f2e-mock\..\target\jacoco-it.exec
10:55:50.578 INFO  - Analysing D:\Users\nb38tv\workspace\WS_F2ECORE_LTD\DG2\core\f2e-mock\target\sonar\jacoco-overall.exec
10:55:50.593 INFO  - No information about coverage per test.
```

Why Sonar cannot find the coberture of classes of A.jar and B.jar??

Regards.

Comment: Sorry, but have you tried to Google "SonarQube No information about coverage per test" ?

Comment: Days and days and no info about this particular case

Comment: Here is one of the first links from Google - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297071/jacoco-sonarqube-no-information-about-coverage-per-test#comment43093247_27297071

Comment: Thanks but I read two first pages of google with that error and none of the solutions it´s thr same as my case. It´s clear my particular case where the maven module does not contain the classes of tje jars which I test againts and I try to get the cobertua

Comment: Why you talk about Cobertura and keep marking your questions with tag JaCoCo ???

Comment: you´re right I change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135858/discussion-between-paul-and-godin).

Answer (score 2):

This sentence does not refer to display of coverage in general, but to the ability of SonarQube to show which test contributes which coverage. This requires some additional configuration - quoting https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin

> Using some unit test listeners you can collect the information on which lines where covered by which tests

and this page also refers to an example at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/ut/ut-maven-jacoco