# Sonar + Jacoco + Junit 5 : No information about coverage per test

Tags: java, sonarqube, junit5, jacoco-maven-plugin, test-coverage

I am trying to get coverage per test feature working with Sonarqube 7.

I am using jacoco-maven-plugin and my tests are running with JUnit 5.

I successfully managed to get global Coverage on Sonarqube dashboard, but I would like to go deeper by being able to see which tests covered which lines of my classes.

I've tried with the given configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265284/856672) but without success : I get the following message in the logs '**No information about coverage per test**'. I see that this can be obtained by adding a listener `org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener`, but it is a JUnit 4 listener, so I guess it is not working because of that.

How can I manage to make the Coverage per test feature work with JUnit 5 ?

Comment: Hi! Could you share how you managed to get global coverage?

Answer (score 2):

I have some problem and solved change version of surefire-plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.2</version>
</plugin>
```